# Is there any command to check if a download is in progress on macos?

Tags: macos, command-line, data-transfer

I want to know if there's a command that let's me monitor whether a file is being downloaded on my mac. I used to use the `netstat -s` followed by a grep to find all the `connections established` but apple seems to have removed it recently due to security reasons.

I've run the command both with and without sudo and it gives me the error

> netstat: sysctl: net.inet.ip.input_perf_data: No such file or directory

The `netstat -s` command isn't the one giving me the error. The error is displayed when I use gerp and try to find the connections established
I'm using macOS 10.13 High Sierra

Comment: `netstat` is still at `/usr/sbin/netstat` in Big Sur, did you run it as `sudo netstat -s`?

Comment: yes i did. Here is the issue i faced https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8652315

Comment: Please edit the question here to make it stand on its own. Sending people to another site for details may lead to downvotes and reduces your chance of getting answers.

Comment: Also, the post on discussions doesn't explain if you used `sudo` or not?

Comment: As I stated in the comment before this, I did use ```sudo``` and it did not work. I've also tried it without ```sudo``` which did not work either.

Comment: Please add that to your original post for clarity.  It really helps people to easily get the information they need to help you, rather than looking in the comments and clicking on another website for important details.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't make it clear. I'll update the main post.

Comment: RE: "The` netstat -s` command isn't the one giving me the error. The error is displayed when I use gerp and try to find the connections established" -- That error has absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with `grep`, as it's an error produced by `netstat` and is produces by it alone or whether the output is piped. I've confirmed this on a system running **macOS High Sierra**.

Answer (score 1):

From `man netstat`:

```
-s    Show per-protocol statistics.  If this option is repeated, counters with a value of zero
      are suppressed.  For security reasons, root privileges are required to read TCP statistics
      and in the absence of such privileges all TCP counters will be reported as zero.
```

So `sudo` **must** be used to get TCP statistics.

```
$ sudo netstat -s | grep -i established
netstat: sysctl: net.inet.ip.input_perf_data: No such file or directory
    198120 connections established (including accepts)
```

Not sure whether established connections are the same as downloads though.

Comment: So the part where ```198120 connections established (including accepts)``` doesn't appear for me. All I get even when I use sudo is ```netstat: sysctl: net.inet.ip.input_perf_data: No such file or directory``` just this nothing else

Comment: @dhanush Hmm, which version of macOS are you using?

Comment: macOS 10.13 High Sierra

Comment: @Dhanush Do you get *any* output (besides the error) if you just run `sudo netstat -s`?

Comment: I do get an output if i just ```sudo netstat -s``` but when I try to use gerp to find the ```connections established``` I get that error and nothing else.

Comment: @Dhanush Might be a good moment to update the question with all the details we figured out now. Remember, we can't see your screen, so whatever answers you may get are solely based on the information you share with us.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for the help so far i'll keep the question updated with all the information i find.